# open source swing applications

Tags: java, swing, open-source

I am a student currently doing my thesis and I would like to have access to open source software, however they need to have a Swing GUI. It would be great if they also have different versions as well. Does any of you maybe know a site where these type of applications can be found please? your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some ideas:

- [Swing research on Google Code](http://code.google.com/query/#q=swing) (go to the "Project hosting" tab)
- The [swing tag on kenai.com](http://kenai.com/projects_tags/swing)
- [Swing search on github](https://github.com/search?q=swing&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1)
- [Swing search on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=swing)

I'm sure you can find a lot of interesting and good quality projects on these open source hosting platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It is open source application that has UI written using Swing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are mainly interested in the Swing GUI and not so much in what the application actually does, you might want to look at the source of all evil:

[SwingSet3](http://java.net/projects/swingset3) is a demonstrator for the Swing GUI, check out versions 1 and 2 also so you'll have an entire development path through three main versions with innumerable revisions.

The same basic type of app can be found in the [SwingX Demonatrator](http://swingx.java.net). Incidentally, both of these are emphatically encouraged to browse through if you want to learn more of the inner workings of Swing / SwingX.

Thirdly, the demo application on [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com) is a more standard application (it actually does something), while also being very well written and documented.

Hope these help.